# How should I connect a pH electrode to my Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, sensor

I am working on a project that involves Raspberry Pi and a pH sensor.

I have this pH electrode (image below) and I need to know steps or procedure to make it work.

[image: pH electrode]

P.S. RPi installed with operating system Raspbian

Comment: If that is all the information you can provide I can't see how an answer can be given unless someone has the identical device.

Comment: what device this that?

Answer (score 3):

In a very general sense:

1. You're going to need to know the output voltage and amperage of
   your sensor.
2. You'll most likely need some kind of digital->analog
   converter to turn the analog output of the sensor into a digital
   signal the Pi can read. You can find one once you know the output of your  sensor. You might also need some kind of power
   convertor to match the signal to the voltage/amperage that the Pi
   expects as input. You can most likely find both of these things on Adafruit Industries' website.
3. Hook it to suitable GPIO pins on the Pi. GPIO pin
   diagrams are all over the Raspberry Pi site to tell you which pins
   are best. This will depend on your sensor and DAC, etc.
4. You'll be able to read the pins via the Python RPi.GPIO library, so you'll need a basic grasp of how to run Python programs on the Pi.

Comment: Thanks so much @yogsodoth ! Now at least I know how to move forward ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which electrode you have, but this guide may be just what you need.

https://myhydropi.com/connecting-a-ph-sensor-to-a-raspberry-pi